# mySQL groupwise minimum and maximum

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to mySQL and I'm fooling around with the groupwise maximum example from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html.

My goal is to get the groupwise maximum and groupwise minimum for each **article**. Here is the schema I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE shop (`article` int(10), `dealer` varchar(10), `price` int(10));

INSERT INTO shop 
    (`article`, `dealer`, `price`)
VALUES
    (26, 'PCS', 120),
    (27, 'PCS', 345),
    (28, 'RDN', 211),
    (29, 'RDN', 99),
    (26, 'PCS', 111);
```

The query I have at the moment:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article) OR price=(SELECT MIN(s3.price)
              FROM shop s3
              WHERE s1.article = s3.article)
ORDER BY article;
```

The result of the above query:

| article | dealer | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | PCS | 120 |
| 26 | PCS | 111 |
| 27 | PCS | 345 |
| 28 | RDN | 211 |
| 29 | RDN | 99 |

I think the query works as it should but I'm trying to achieve the following output:

| article | dealer | max_price | min_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | PCS | 120 | 111 |
| 27 | PCS | 345 | 345 |
| 28 | RDN | 211 | 211 |
| 29 | RDN | 99 | 99 |

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85e6c7/18)

How do I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85e6c7/24

Comment: What if the dealer for the max and the dealer for the min were two different people?

Comment: Hi @Strawberry. Thank you for your response. I think I understand what you're describing and I see where the issue comes in. If the dealer column is removed will your solution work?

Comment: Yes, if you also remove dealer from the GROUP BY (this seems kind of obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subqueries are not required. This query will get you min and max by article and dealer

```
SELECT article, dealer, max(price) as max_price, min(price) as min_price
FROM   shop s1
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

in case dealers are different for the same article you can use this

```
SELECT article, max(price) as max_price, min(price) as min_price
    FROM   shop s1
    group by 1
    order by 1
```

Comment: `group by 1,2`?

Comment: 1 and 2 are references for first and second column